# Texture Loading in LWJGL 3 - follow-up

Tags: java, image, opengl, lwjgl

Here's my optimized `Texture` class:

```
public class Texture {

    /**
     * Stores the handle of the texture.
     */
    private final int id;

    /**
     * Width of the texture.
     */
    private int width;

    /**
     * Height of the texture.
     */
    private int height;

    /** Creates a texture. */
    public Texture() {
        id = glGenTextures();
    }

    /**
     * Binds the texture.
     */
    public void bind() {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    }

    /**
     * Sets a parameter of the texture.
     *
     * @param name  Name of the parameter
     * @param value Value to set
     */
    public void setParameter(int name, int value) {
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, name, value);
    }

    /**
     * Uploads image data with specified width and height.
     *
     * @param width  Width of the image
     * @param height Height of the image
     * @param data   Pixel data of the image
     */
    public void uploadData(int width, int height, ByteBuffer data) {
        uploadData(GL_RGBA8, width, height, GL_RGBA, data);
    }

    /**
     * Uploads image data with specified internal format, width, height and
     * image format.
     *
     * @param internalFormat Internal format of the image data
     * @param width          Width of the image
     * @param height         Height of the image
     * @param format         Format of the image data
     * @param data           Pixel data of the image
     */
    public void uploadData(int internalFormat, int width, int height, int format, ByteBuffer data) {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the texture.
     */
    public void delete() {
        glDeleteTextures(id);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the texture width.
     *
     * @return Texture width
     */
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the texture width.
     *
     * @param width The width to set
     */
    public void setWidth(int width) {
        if (width > 0) {
            this.width = width;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the texture height.
     *
     * @return Texture height
     */
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the texture height.
     *
     * @param height The height to set
     */
    public void setHeight(int height) {
        if (height > 0) {
            this.height = height;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a texture with specified width, height and data.
     *
     * @param width  Width of the texture
     * @param height Height of the texture
     * @param data   Picture Data in RGBA format
     *
     * @return Texture from the specified data
     */
    public static Texture createTexture(int width, int height, ByteBuffer data) {
        Texture texture = new Texture();
        texture.setWidth(width);
        texture.setHeight(height);

        texture.bind();

        texture.setParameter(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
        texture.setParameter(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
        texture.setParameter(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        texture.setParameter(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        texture.setParameter(GL14.GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL11.GL_TRUE);

        texture.uploadData(GL_RGBA8, width, height, GL_RGBA, data);

        return texture;
    }

    /**
     * Load texture from file.
     *
     * @param path File path of the texture
     *
     * @return Texture from specified file
     */
    public static Texture loadTexture(String path) {
        ByteBuffer image;
        int width, height;

        try (MemoryStack stack = MemoryStack.stackPush()) {
            /* Prepare image buffers */
            IntBuffer w = stack.mallocInt(1);
            IntBuffer h = stack.mallocInt(1);
            IntBuffer comp = stack.mallocInt(1);

            /* Load image */
            URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(path);
            image = stbi_load(url.getPath(), w, h, comp, 4);
            if (image == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load a texture file!" + System.lineSeparator() + stbi_failure_reason());
            }

            /* Get width and height of image */
            width = w.get();
            height = h.get();
        }

        stbi_image_free(image);
        return createTexture(width, height, image);
    }
}
```

I use it as follows:

```
GL11.glPushMatrix();
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

background.bind();

GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

GL11.glTexCoord2f(0F, 0F);
GL11.glVertex2f(-1F, 1F);

GL11.glTexCoord2f(1F, 0F);
GL11.glVertex2f(1F, 1F);

GL11.glTexCoord2f(1F, 1F);
GL11.glVertex2f(1F, -1F);

GL11.glTexCoord2f(0F, 1F);
GL11.glVertex2f(-1F, -1F);

GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL11.glEnd();
GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

where `background` is a declared `Texture` that throws no errors.

Comment: If this doesn't already handle .gif images, then it would be off-topic here to ask how it should be implemented.

Comment: Hey, could you explain why there is a `setWidth` and `setHeight`? Should this not be set always dependent on the image data?

Comment: @zeluisping By default, they are dependent on image data. If you look at the `uploadData` method it should answer your question. That's what actually does the rendering, and we can resize the image using it.